# How to use Ubuntu 12.10 from a USB stick in a Lenovo ideapad G580 with Windows 8?

Tags: installation, live-usb

I have a Lenovo ideapad g580 with Windows 8 from the box.

When I insert a USB stick with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, it is just giving me to try it, not to run it from the USB.

When I put it on my other laptop it is just running and I can save data and files, and when I shutdown the laptop the data aren't deleted.

And on the Lenovo when I work on Ubuntu, all the data after restarting the system are deleted.

Comment: *it is just giving me to try it, not to run it from the USB* Is not the same thing? Also, **where** the data is saved in the *other* computer? If you want to **install** Ubuntu in the USB flash drive review this post: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](http://askubuntu.com/q/16988/62483)

Answer (score 0):

I am also on a Windows 8 Lenovo ideapad (Z580). I don't know what is going wrong with yours, but I think you might be able to help me...
Does your Windows 8 still work after you unplug the USB stick? I want to use ubuntu but if it breaks my Windows 8 then I had better not...
Sorry I can't be more useful in answering your question...
How did you get Ubuntu onto the USB - I know you probably already know this, but try using PenDriveLinux and persistence mode. I haven't tried it but it's supposed to make the USB remember each session like on a normal pc.

Comment: Yes my windows 8 still works without problems, but you must be careful when installing ubuntu. Anyway thanks for your advice. :D